# Where to find BitTorrent source code?

Tags: bittorrent

I have looked and looked and cannot seem to find this source code anywhere.  Every link I find points to the official BitTorrent page, which Slashdot says took the source code down in 2007. Am I to believe that this incredibly widespread, open-source technology is not to be found anywhere except in applications like uTorrent or Transmission?
There has to be a place to download CURRENT source code for BitTorrent.
Can anyone point me to that magical place?

Comment: in addition to what @skaffman says, if you want the source code to a bittorrent _client_, your best bet is to take a look at the open source ones out there, like Transmission (http://www.transmissionbt.com/), and my personal favourite KTorrent (http://ktorrent.org/)

Comment: I am definitely looking for the actual original bittorrent source code.  Or at least the last released code prior to it being made not open-source anymore.  There has to be SOMEONE out there who has it and has it publicly available.

Comment: @skaffman BitTorrent was an application which is re-branded as uTorrent now AND a protocol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FYI Archived version of the original Bittorrent application (also known as Mainline, particularly to those developing other bt clients) are available here, back to 3.9.1.

[http://download.bittorrent.com/dl/archive/](http://web.archive.org/web/20110712221649/http://download.bittorrent.com/dl/archive/)

For example, I can confirm the BitTorrent-3.9.1-1.noarch.rpm contains the python source. The RPM format can be opened using common archive utilities. On OSX, I used Keka to unarchive to a cpio, then Keka again to unarchive into the file structure (I can see python scripts to do common bt tasks under usr/bin/ and the various code under usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/BitTorrent )

When they switched to uTorrent codebase, the code became closed. As mentioned by others, there are many open source alternatives to the Bittorrent client offered by bittorrent.com.

---

Edit May 3, 2013: Bittorrent appear to no longer share their archive. You can still download the source via CVS, last updated in 2005. http://sourceforge.net/p/bittorrent/code/?source=navbar

Comment: Thanks man ! utorrent is great, but the fact its closed source means there are people not wanting to have more of those kinds of techs grow up in the future. It's sad, I so much want to make everything in p2p and DHT, chat, forums, mail...

Comment: well I can't even find it on bittorrent

Comment: the link is not workin

Comment: It seems releases are unavailable - maybe they'll come back. Until then access the code in CVS on sourceforge. Instructions to read from the bittorrent CVS repository are here:  http://sourceforge.net/p/bittorrent/code/?source=navbar

Answer (score 7):

The latest available source of BitTorrent was published in 2009 at BitTorrent website as [BitTorrent-5.3-GPL.tar.gz](http://web.archive.org/web/20100330145634/http://www.bittorrent.com/btusers/download/directory-list) under GPL/GNU license.

It's version 5.3, however other version between 2.9.5 and 5.3.0 are also available.

You can checkout this version from [GitHub](https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/BitTorrent) (with full release history). Also available [here](https://github.com/santazhang/BitTorrent-5.3-GPL).

---

Alternative open-source projects includes:

- [WebTorrent](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent) - a streaming torrent client for node.js

Answer (score 4):

Version 5.0.9 seemingly (not sure if it's to be trusted) can be found here:

http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/bittorrent_linux.cfm

Version 3.x is on SourceForge:

http://bittorrent.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bittorrent/BitTorrent/

Answer (score 3):

The source is closed for uTorrent and has always been. The fact that BitTorrent is now a re-branded uTorrent makes it also closed, even though they closed it a few years back.

Therefore if you are looking for *CURRENT* source to BitTorrent/uTorrent you would be doing so illegally.

If you are looking for archived source for versions which were previously released as OSS then your best bet may ironically be the varying search mechanisms for torrents.

Answer (score 2):

The Source code is available officially at

[Here](http://bittorrent.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bittorrent/)

Answer (score 1):

BitTorrent is a protocol, which makes me wonder if you are asking about this:

http://bittorrent.github.com/apps-sdk

"The Apps for BitTorrent SDK is a collection of tools, libraries and documentation to make the process of creating, authoring and testing apps as easy as possible."